# php-pdo-mysql-version-minimum v1 (detected: OFF) in magento

Tags: magento

i am trying to install magento from cpanel but following errors displaying

> ! The selected version 1.9.1.0 is not compatible with the selected
>   install location.

**Requirements:**
php-pdo-mysql-version-minimum v1 (detected: OFF)

i tried to select other version of magento but same errors displaying.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A number of apps require the PDO MYSQL PHP extension, which is not standard on all hosting control panels. Magento also require the extension, but your web host doesn't have it. For detailed information of installing PDO MYSQL, check this page http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php